# How to install Virtualbox Guest Additions in Kali Linux:

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kali-linux

I have a problem with my Kali Linux, I am getting an error while installing virtual box guest addition. I have Windows 8.1 64-bit and I have installed virtual box latest version 4.3.28 in my windows. I have installed latest version of Kali Linux **"1.1.0 32-bit"** in my virtual box successfully. But when I install virtual box guest additions in it it shows error. The error is occurring when I run this command in my terminal

```
 "apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) -y"
```

Please help me to install virtual box guest additions in the correct way.

And I am getting the following error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-686-pae
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-686-pae'
```

Answer (score 2):

Mine was fixed by editing /etc/apt/sources.list to the following:

```
# Regular Repositories 
deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib 
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free

# Source Repositories 
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib 
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

Then running:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Source: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?26478-cant-install-linux-header-kali-sana-vmware-player&p=47698&viewfull=1#post47698

Then running:

```
apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkm
```

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't need external mediation except for a few options. Try running the install.pl or such script in the mounted iso directly. The headers can't be found by apt, they are generated in the Linux installation process itself. They are a core part of Linux distros (at least in Debian and derivatives), so they aren't in the repos.

Reinstall Kali & try again to install the guest additions. Extract the `.iso` file to a location under 
`/usr/` and execute `install.pl` or `install.sh`

Comment: But I want to copy and paste between host and guest and without installing virtualbox guest additions I can' t do this.

Comment: this is an answer or question?, this should be posted as comment than answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment. however, this is an answer. the question should be elaborated more.

Comment: somehow i can comment now. ok, i'll put these things into comments now onwards

Comment: You can always comment on your own posts. You need [50 rep to comment on others' posts](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).