# Unable to install VirtualBox guest additions on Kali Linux

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux, guest-additions

I have been trying to install the VirtualBox guest additions onto my Kali Linux VM for the past couple of days now and I am at a loss for why it's not working.

For starters, the host machine is running Windows 10. I am running VirtualBox version 5.1.18. In addition, I have been using Kali Linux version 2016.2 for a 64 bit OS.

I have tried several different methods for installing the guest additions. The first method was inserting the guest CD under the devices menu for my virtual machine. I was able to see the disk on the desktop of the vm but when I tried to launch the software inside it errored with the message: Cannot find program.

I then tried the official way on the Kali Linux docs found [here](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-virtual-box-guest). Those commands worked fine and things were installed. However, upon reboot the seamless mode and auto-resize guest option for my virtual machine were still greyed out.

I tried doing those two methods twice, each with a brand new virtual machine.

My final method came from SuperUser as found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/928570/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-kali-linux). I followed the comment talking about editing `/etc/apt/sources.list`. The commands below it worked until the `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` command. The virtual machine errored saying:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.6.0-kali-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.6.0-kali-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.6.0-kali-amd64'
```

If anyone knows how to get this to work please let me know.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is 5 years old, has 3 answers already and the original poster has not indicated in any way if any of the solutions worked. Thus this question seems to be abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

Try this procedure:

1. install linux headers

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms
   ```
2. mount CD VBoxGuestAdditions
3. get into that cd and run

   ```
   sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
   ```

Wait until it installs and reboot the VM

Comment: kali-linux-2023.3-installer-amd64 is missing the kernel headers, this is the way to install it

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
apt-get purge virtualbox-guest-x11
apt-get autoremove --purge
reboot
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
reboot
apt-get update
apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-x11
reboot
```

Comment: works fine for me also, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Linux kali 4.14.0-kali3-amd64

```
apt-get remove && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y
reboot
apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-x11
reboot
```

Then

```
apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
mount /usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso /mnt
cd /mnt
./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
reboot
```

or

Virtual Box Menu: Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD..

```
mkdir VBox
cp -Rv /media/cdrom0/* ~/Vbox/
cd Vbox/
./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
reboot
```